# How to reduce the gap between bars on bar chart

Tags: angular, ionic2, chart.js

How to reduce the gap between bars.when I tried this example width is increasing I want only space reducing without increasing width how to do?

[image]

```
 options: {
        responsive: false,
         scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                      categoryPercentage: 0.3,
                       barPercentage: 0.3,
                      }],
                }
          }
```

Output should be like this

[image]

Comment: are you using ionic v1 or 2?

Comment: i am using v2(ionic2)

Comment: ok... then you would be using angular 2+ not angularjs..please use the correct tags

Comment: sorry for wrong updation i will change.but what is the correct answer then

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the  bar width argument within the options section.
Example from: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/CustomBarWidth/AngularJS/Contrast/

```
 scope.chartOptions = {
        palette: "soft",
        dataSource: dataSource,

        //THIS COMMAND
        barWidth: 0.5,

        commonSeriesSettings: {
            argumentField: "state",
            type: "bar"
        },
```

Comment: Tried barwidth:0.5  but no changes..@user2589273

Comment: bar width is increasing...i want only reduce the space between bars without increasing width.

Comment: not sure if this answer applies since OP is using ionic 2 and angular 2+